# Python article collection from a website that requires cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-3.x, web-scraping, data-collection

I'm trying to collect articles from the databases at infoweb.newsbank.com for research I'm doing at University. So far this is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib
from requests import session
import http.cookiejar


mainLink  = "http://infoweb.newsbank.com.proxy.lib.uiowa.edu/iw-search/we/InfoWeb?p_product=AWNB&p_theme=aggregated5&p_action=doc&p_docid=14D12E120CD13C18&p_docnum=2&p_queryname=4"




def articleCrawler(mainUrl):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(mainUrl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
    linkList = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link)

articleCrawler(mainLink)
```

Unfortunatrly I get back this response:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cookie Required</title>
</head>
<body>
This is cookie.htm from the doc subdirectory.
<p>
<hr>
<p>

Licensing agreements for these databases require that access be extended
only to authorized users.  Once you have been validated by this system,
a "cookie" is sent to your browser as an ongoing indication of your authorization to
access these databases.  It will only need to be set once during login.
<p>
As you access databases, they may also use cookies.  Your ability to use those databases
may depend on whether or not you allow those cookies to be set.
<p>
To login again, click <a href="login">here</a>.
</p></p></p></hr></p></body>
</html>

<a href="login">here</a>
```

I've tried using http.cookiejar, but I am not familiar with the library. I am using Python 3. Does anyone know how to accept the cookie and access the article? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Python3, but in Python2 the standard way to accept cookies is to incorporate a `HTTPCookieProcessor` as one of the handlers in your `OpenerDirector`.

So, something like this:

```
import cookielib, urllib, urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))
```

`opener` is now ready to open a URL (presumably with a username and password) and place any cookies it receives into its integrated CookieJar:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'username': 'someuser', 'password': 'somepass'})
opener.open(LOGIN_URL, params)
```

If the login was successful, `opener` will now have whatever authentication token the server gave it sitting around in cookie form.  Then you just access the link you wanted in the first place:

```
f = opener.open(mainLink)
```

Again, not sure how this translates for Python3, but I think you at least want `cookielib.CookieJar` rather than `http.cookiejar`.  I think the latter is for creating HTTP cookie content as a server rather than for receiving cookie content as a client.

Comment: Ok, I will check that out and comment back later. Thank you.